Código para iniciar sesión
Buen día
Hace la validación correctamente y me ingresa al Panel.  La tabla llamada USER de la base de datos tiene los siguientes campos:  id, nombre, usuario,  contraseña, status.
Donde en el campo STATUS su valor puede ser VERIFIED o NOTVERIFIED, entonces quiero que para poder ingresar al PANEL cuando el usuario este en VERIFIED, agradezco la colaboración.
El formulario para iniciar sesión con el siguiente código:
<?php
include("php/dbconnect.php");
$error = '';
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$username =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_POST['username']));
$password =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
if($username=='' || $password=='')
{
$error='All fields are required';
}
$sql = "select * from user where username='".$username."' and password = '".md5($password)."'";
$q = $conn->query($sql);
if($q->num_rows==1)
{
$res = $q->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['rainbow_username']=$res['username'];
$_SESSION['rainbow_uid']=$res['id'];
$_SESSION['rainbow_name']=$res['name'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="index.php"; </script>';
}
else 
{
$error = 'Invalid Username or Password';
}
}
?>


Si solamente lo que buscas filtrar, es si son VERIFIED, por que no agregar el condicional al final?
Agregando un AND y verificando status = 'VERIFIED', cumples la condición que solicitas.
$sql = "select * from user where username='".$username."' and password = '".md5($password)."' and status = 'VERIFIED'";

Ahora, tu código aún necesita muchas mejoras, pero debe ser que estás aprendiendo.
Estás usando variables de sesión $_SESSION, pero no has inicializado la sesión antes con session_start(). Al inicio del código, deberías tener:
<?php
include("php/dbconnect.php");
session_start();

Podrías evitar inyecciones SQL en tu código, en especial durante un login. Entonces realizamos una consulta preparada, para más seguridad.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=? AND password=? AND status='VERIFIED'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$hashed_password = md5($password);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $hashed_password);

Durante la misma consulta, es mejor llamar a los campos que necesitas, en vez de * que es TODO
"SELECT id, nombre, usuario, contraseña, status FROM user"

Detener el script, luego de la redirección. Luego de redireccionar, tu código se sigue ejecutando, por lo que es mejor terminarlo ahí mismo.
//Redirección
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="index.php";</script>';
exit(); //Finalizamos el script

Y por último, el uso de MD5, podrías cambiarlo por password_hash() y password_verify(). Esto debido a que son mejores en cuanto a seguridad que el MD5. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
//Para guardar la contraseña
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

//PPara verificar la contraseña
if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
    //Contraseña correcta
}


Gracias por tu respuesta evidentemente es lo que necesitaba, Pero quiero añadir otra pregunta lo cual no entiendo como hacerlo, como hago para que las validaciones se hagan por separado, te explico, QUE EL MENSAJE DE ERROR SEA POR SEPARADO, UN MENSAJE DE ERROR DEL USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA Y UN MENSAJE DE VERIFIED.

Debes evaluar cada condición por separado, un IF por cada uno es lo más simple.

@user400020 Una pregunta por vez, siempre puedes generar una nueva (son gratis).  Recuerda que si esta respuesta te ha ayudado puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos

No es necesario para una respuesta tan simple. Si luego de intentar, tiene problemas o no entiende como hacer los IF, puede venir con una nueva publicación. Y si por favor @user400020, marca la respuesta si puedes, ayuda bastante.
